# cant remove whitespaces from hexadecimal string EXCEL

Tags: excel, replace

I have an excel file with one column with hexadecimal values in this format: `00 00 00` and I want to change them into decimal values so I tried using `REPLACE` to remove white spaces:

```
=REPLACE(A1," ", , "")
```

but what I got was `#VALUE!`

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert from hexadecimal to decimal, merely removing white space from a certain format won't do that. Use the function `HEX2DEC()` instead. To apply it, you do need to remove the spaces:

```
=HEX2DEC(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ",""))
```

Comment: Using that on a the format I have results in #NUM!. The type of the cell is 2 (text)

Answer (score 0):

I used `=HEX2DEC(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))` and that worked, so I guess `SUBSTITUTE` works better here than `REPLACE`

Comment: Replace needed a start number, you were trying to pass it a string in that parameter. But, you are correct that `Substitute` is often more convenient than `Replace`